# MYSQL count different values of a row with distinct value of another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using the below query i'm able to get the count of male and female of each municipality but the problem is municipalities come in duplicate entries, I want all same municipalities to come in one row and all their male and females be counted all together. Someone please help me :(

I need the data of Gender and Training Location columns of the table2 and it is inner join with table1 because for each record of table1 I have many records in table2.

**Please refer to the below picture of what i currently get through this query**

```
Select 
  (Select count(*) from table2 where gender='Male' and table1.ID=table2.ID) AS Male, 
  (Select count(*) from table2 where gender='Female' and table1.ID=table2.ID) AS Female,  
  Training_Location 
from table2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.ID 
WHERE table1.Training_Start_Date BETWEEN '$StartDate' and '$EndDate' 
group by table1.ID
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: group by municipality

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: Also **stop** injection your values! Parametrise!

Comment: Please provide sample data, actual and desired results. It is rather unclear what each table contains.

Comment: @GMB I have made some changes on it, please check the query again and also its out put screen shot.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, i'm using MYSQL

Comment: @Vidal it doesnt work either. :(

Comment: Anyone looking at your query can see the names of the columns returned and know that the first two columns will be integers. Your image is of no help. What you should do is go to a website such as db-fiddle.com and create some tables with some sample data that will be a Minimal Reproducible Example showing us your actual input table structure. Then update your question with a link to the db-fiddle and what you would want the expected output to be for the data you have inputted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the `JOIN` in the outer query:

```
select t1.id, t1.Training_Location 
       (Select count(*) from table2 t2 where t2.gender='Male' and t1.I D= t2.ID) AS Male, 
       (Select count(*) from tbl_ind1_sub tis where tis.gender ='Female' and t1.ID = tis.ID) AS Female,  
from table1 t1 ON table1.id = table2.ID 
where t1.Training_Start_Date between ? and ?;
```

It seems *really* strange to me that males and females would be in separate tables.  But that is how your question is structured.

Note that no `group by` is needed in the outer query, assuming the `id` is unique (a reasonable assumption).

Also, do not munge queries with constants.  Pass them into the query as parameters.

If you decide that the tables in the subquery are the same table, ask a *new* question.  This question clearly has them as separate tables.